# Copy two properties from one array item to matching index in another array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two IEnumerable objects called `items` and `newItems`.  I need to update the `Did` and `KeyDid` property of each element in `items` with the matching `Did` and `KeyDid` from `newItems`.  I can't just call `items = newItems;` since other things have a reference to `items`.  Here's my code:

```
T[] arrItems = items as T[] ?? items.ToArray();
if (arrItems.Length != newItems.Count())
    throw new Exception("Item counts do not match.");

//Copy Did and KeyDid from old items to newItems
int i = 0;
foreach (T newItem in newItems)
{
    T oldItem = arrItems[i++];
    oldItem.Did = newItem.Did;
    oldItem.KeyDid = newItem.KeyDid;
}
```

I'm interested in a more concise way to do this, perhaps using a single LINQ expression.  Any ideas how to improve this code in terms of readability, clearness, conciseness, or overall coolness?

Comment: Not sure about the only enumerate once comment.  You are possible already enumerating twice by doing the .Count() call earlier???

Comment: @dreza - Good call.  The `.Count()` call should be moved to after the `.ToArray()` - I'll update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (arrItems.Length != newItems.Count())
        // --> BAD throw new Exception("Item counts do not match.");
        // Do not throw the Exception base here look for the real exception for example ArgumentException(if the arr come from arguments) or your custom exception:
        throw new ArgumentException();

      //Copy Did and KeyDid from old items to newItems
      for (var index = 0; index < newItems.Length; index++)
      {
        arrItems[index].Did = newItems[index].Did;
        arrItems[index].KeyDid = newItems[index].KeyDid;
      }
```

I do not think LINQ will give you a better solution than what you have above; you can use group by or select to create a new element in the linq query and than put it back to object! "For" in this case is very fast and it solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  Yea looks like just looping through the list is the way to go.  The `Exception` was just for demonstration purposes; we have our own exception classes in our *actual* code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

```
if (arrItems.Length == newItems.Count())
{
    newItems = newItems.Zip(arrItems, (newItem, arrItem) =>
        {
            newItem.KeyDid = arrItem.KeyDid;
            newItem.Did = arrItem.Did;
            return newItem;
        });                
}
```

The Zip method basically merges two enumerables by invoking the specified delegate and passing the items of the two arrays as parameters. Makes for concise code.

Comment: Looks like you're copying from `arrItems` to `newItems` which is the opposite of what I want.  Either way, this approach won't work.  You're creating a new list, which is then lost when the function exits.  Plus, the code would never be run unless you materialized the list.  This approach seems hacky to me.